# Javascript get or set value instead of just renaming something

Tags: javascript, jquery, pointers

I am having an issue in Javascript, and frankly it's confusing in a lot of what I am doing. Is there any way in Javascript to assign an actual value to a variable without literally doing so? It is kind of a pointer issue I guess, though I am unfamiliar with pointers.

For example, when I do this:

```
myVar = $(".myClass").height();
```

I am not setting myVar equal to the value returned, I am setting myVar equal to the function so that myVar is always checked again when it is called. I want myVar to be equal to a literal number after the assignment. Therefore, it cannot change when the variable is called again.

For instance if the height was first 12, then I did my code above, myVar would now equal 12. And even after the height was changed to 16, the myVar variable would have a value of 12.

Is there a way around this? Could someone identify what this is called so I can do more research? This becomes difficult when I need the value returned by a function as a constant..

I know that Mozilla has a const type, but that is not supported by IE.

Any help would be great!

EDIT:

Just to reiterate! myVar changes every time I call this after the height changes. That is wrong though, and I can't figure out how to stop it!

Comment: _"I am not setting myVar equal to the value returned..."_ Mmm, yes you are...

Comment: `.height()` return's an Integer.

Comment: Javascript uses literals (with numbers supported) so it is in fact the actual value that is saved and not a pointer.

Comment: You're using jQuery. Call it that way, instead just javascript as you did in the question. 
But would this help: $('.myclass').attr('height', 20);
Where 20 is the desired height.

Comment: I think he is looking for a pointer to the actual value. You'll have to do this with an event listener on the element's resize. EDIT: Probably got that wrong. You have the literal value already, it would only be replaced with the new height if you re-run the assignment

Comment: I don't want to set the variable, I want to be able to access the variable as originally assigned despite changes in the property.

Comment: @phileaton - That is what you are doing.

Comment: If you're seeing the value change, then you're running that line again somewhere.

Comment: @Tasos, that must be it then

Comment: @phileaton - Here is a sample: http://jsfiddle.net/44tMa/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var myVar = myVar===undefined ? $(".myClass").height() : myVar; 
//first time, assign. second time, ignore and retain initial value.
```

edit: added "var" because: OCD.

Answer (score 1):

In javascript there are actually 2 kind of objects. Pointers(that means that they store an address of data) and variables(they store an actual data). The tricky part is the assignment operator.
When you are assigning a function to a variable, the resulting var will be a pointer. For instance:

```
var myPointer = MyObject();
```

But that

```
var myVariable = 3;
```

Will assign the variable an actual value. In your example you are assigning a value.

Answer (score 1):

Here it is some working samples if you want to play with it.

http://jsfiddle.net/Madthew/Xfass/3/

```
var myVar2 = myVar2===undefined ? $(".myClass").height() : myVar2;
$(document).ready(function() {
  myVar = $('.myClass').height();

});

$("#btn").click(function() {
    resize();
});
```